# Passing C++ double arrays (pointer to pointer) to Python script

Tags: c++, python, pointers, boost-python

I'm trying to pass a C++ class with some 2D array member variables to a Python script. The 2D arrays are allocated directly into the class, independent of the constructor. I am using the boost_python library for this conversion and a wrapper function wich uses the add_property/reference_existing_object function expecting this to make a new Python 2D array from the double pointer of the C++ script.

However, I get an error telling me that boost cannot convert from const double to double when handling the arrays. But the arrays should not be set to be const in the first place should they? It is possible that I'm way of here. I'm new to boost, and there's been a while since I wrote C++, so I hope some of you can help explain this in a simple way:) How could I pass these arrays if my approach isn't the way to go?

I'm posting the class and wrapper function here for reference.

```
class Interface 
{
public:

   double zUpPatch1[NVALUES_UPSWEEP][N_VALUES_IN_TUPLE+1];
   double zUpPatch2[NVALUES_UPSWEEP][N_VALUES_IN_TUPLE+1];
   double zDownPatch1[NVALUES_UPSWEEP][N_VALUES_IN_TUPLE+1];
   double zDownPatch2[NVALUES_UPSWEEP][N_VALUES_IN_TUPLE+1];

   bool bNewData[N_VALUES_IN_TUPLE+1];
   int mrows, ncols;

   Interface();
   void GetRawData(int);
};

Interface::Interface()
{
   mrows = NVALUES_UPSWEEP;
   ncols = N_VALUES_IN_TUPLE+1;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(GetRawDataPy_ext)
{
   using namespace boost::python;

   class_<Interface>("Interface", init<>())
     .def("GetRawData", &Interface::GetRawData)
     .def_readwrite("mrows", &Interface::mrows)
     .def_readwrite("ncols", &Interface::ncols)
     .def_readwrite("bNewData", &Interface::bNewData)

     .add_property("zUpPatch1",
     make_getter(&Interface::zUpPatch1, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()),
     make_setter(&Interface::zUpPatch1, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()))

     .add_property("zUpPatch2",
     make_getter(&Interface::zUpPatch2, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()),
     make_setter(&Interface::zUpPatch2, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()))

     .add_property("zDownPatch1",
     make_getter(&Interface::zDownPatch2, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()),
     make_setter(&Interface::zDownPatch2, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()))

     .add_property("zDownPatch2",
     make_getter(&Interface::zDownPatch2, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()),
     make_setter(&Interface::zDownPatch2, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()))

     .add_property("bNewData",
     make_getter(&Interface::bNewData, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()),
     make_setter(&Interface::bNewData, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()))
  ;
}
```

Here's an outtake of the error message from the boost compiler:

```
C:\...\.../data_members.hpp(64) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 
'const double [1000][5]' to double [1000][5]'
          There is no context in wich this conversion is possible
C:\...\.../data_members.hpp(63) : while compiling class template member function 
'void boost::python::detail::member<Data,Class>::operator ()(Class &,const double (&))   const'
    with
    [
        Data=double [1000][5],
        Class=Class
    ]
```

Thanks in advance!